# How do I update a specific value inside an Immutable List?

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

I'm working on a [redux](http://redux.js.org/) Architecture, trying to use [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/).

Here's my mystery... given this state:

```
var state = Immutable.fromJS([
  {"id":0, "url":"http://someUrl", "thumb_url":"http://someUrl", "other_url":"http://someUrl"},
  {"id":3, "url":"http://someUrl", "thumb_url":"http://someUrl", "alternative_url":"http://someUrl"},
  {"id":1, "url":"http://someUrl", "thumb_url":"http://someUrl", "alternative_url":"http://someUrl"},
  {"id":5, "url":"http://someUrl", "thumb_url":"http://someUrl", "yet_another_url":"http://someUrl"}
])
```

...I want to update a `url`. I've tried updating the `url` of the third `index` like this:

```
var index = 2;
var new_item = { id: 1, url: 'my_new_url' };

var state = state.setIn([index], new_item);
```

My problem is that I need to update only the `url` (or other properties like `thumb_url`), leaving all unchanged properties untouched. I have a `new_item` of which I want to insert the relevant updated parts into the given index. How do I do that without recursing over every individual property of the old item and without losing the existing properties?

When I say "update", I mean creating a new `state` with the old value(s) changed to the new one(s) as it is common to do with Immutable.js.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[setIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn) will set a new value, which will overwrite your previous value, you may want a [mergeIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/mergeIn) to merge the new attr to origin value.

```js
var state = Immutable.fromJS([
  {"id":0, "url":"http://someUrl", "thumb_url":"http://someUrl", "other_url":"http://someUrl"},
  {"id":3, "url":"http://someUrl", "thumb_url":"http://someUrl", "alternative_url":"http://someUrl"},
  {"id":1, "url":"http://someUrl", "thumb_url":"http://someUrl", "alternative_url":"http://someUrl"},
  {"id":5, "url":"http://someUrl", "thumb_url":"http://someUrl", "yet_another_url":"http://someUrl"}
])

var index = 2;
var new_item = { id: 1, url: 'my_new_url' };
var state = state.mergeIn([index], new_item);
console.log(state.toJS())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.7.5/immutable.min.js"></script>
```